# node.js Клиент получает старый(предыдущий) запрос

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, express

Есть приложение на node + express + mongoose

Проблема в том, что новый пользователь получает данные, которые запрашивались перед ним и т.д.

```
var express = require('express');
var http = require('http');
var path = require('path');
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
var async = require('async');
var fs = require('fs');
var crossroads = require('crossroads');

var base = __dirname;

var app = express();
var port = 4040;

http.createServer(app).listen(port);

app.engine("ejs", require("ejs-locals"));
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.use(express.favicon());
app.use(express.logger('dev'));
app.use(express.bodyParser());
app.use(express.cookieParser('your secret here'));
app.use(app.router);
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost/youtube-v")
.then(() => console.log("Mongo has started..."))
.catch(e => console.log(e));

var myRes = ""

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  require("./models/person");
  const Person = mongoose.model("persons");

  var typeRoute = crossroads.addRoute('/id{id}');
  typeRoute.matched.add(onTypeAccess);

  function onTypeAccess(id) {
    Person
    .find({id: id})
    .then(persons => {
      myRes = JSON.stringify(persons, null, 2);
    })
    .catch();
  };

  crossroads.parse(req.url);

  next();
});

app.use(function(req, res) {
  console.log(myRes);
  res.end(myRes);
})
```

Comment: Зачем у вас myRes глобальный?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для решения посмотрите что получает первый пользователь и то как формируется отправка этих данных,  попробуйте извлекать через. Person
    .findOne({_id: id}, (err, user) =>{} ) ;